# Как правильно писать в Visual C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
  cout << "hello\n"; 
  return 0; 
}
```

Почему эта простая программа в Visual C++ выдает ошибку?

Comment: Надо писать не `include <iostream>` а `#include <iostream>`. А вообще вопрос из разряда "подземных стуков". Текст не отформатирован, сообщение об ошибке отсутствует. Обратитесь к телепатам.

Answer (score 1):

Этот простой код компилируется и исполняется в Visual Studio Express. Единственное, что приходит в голову, это отсутствие предкомпилированных заголовков в проекте консольного приложения. Добавьте в начале файла

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

и посмотрите на результат.

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно. Не должно быть никакой ошибки.